# Returns True if two cells contains at least a common character in GOOGLE SHEET

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, return, character

I would like it to return true in C1 if A1 and B1 have at least one common character.

```
A                                      B


1,7,12                              1,2,8
1,8                                 3,5,12
12,14,20                            1,12,7
```

Comment: overall or row by row? does comma count? does 1 count in teens?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(A1:A3, "\b"&SUBSTITUTE(B1:B3, ",", "|")&"\b"))
```

[image]